# How do I find out the maximum throughout of multiple connected bluetooth devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been searching for a long time on and off for this and have found inconsistent answers.

I want to collect data from several bluetooth devices. As of bluetooth v4.1, android bluetooth low energy devices support multiple simultaneous connections. I have the Sony xperia Z5, connected to 4 different devices.

- 1 smartwatch streaming IMU data in a DataMap at 50Hz, 16 bytes each (each event consists of 4 floats)
- another device streaming similar data at 50Hz, 16 bytes each (each of 4 floats)
- a third streaming 36 bytes at 50Hz (9 floats), and a separate stream of 16 bytes at 100Hz.

This is ignoring the header sizes of the packets (as I don't know them). This is 4kbps, doubling it for error sake is still very low and I think should be perfectly acceptable.

However, I can't find any information on how this is effected because the information comes from different streams. Does anyone know if this makes a difference ?

(additionally, before its pointed out to me, I have thought about saving an array of data on the smartwatch and sending it all in one chunk by adding an array to the DataMap.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try it and see is the only answer to this sort of question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that this will be the only method to know for sure. However I should have mentioned that I cant simply try it as I need to know it has a fair chance of working before I develop a business case around procurement of all the sensors. I don't physically have all the equipment but I know what I plan to do with it. I'm asking for any guidance from anyone who has had experience with multiple simultaneous Bluetooth connections.

Comment: No experience with higher rates like 50 Hz.  Experience with multiple sensors like HR, Bike Speed and cadence and Bike power where it's typically 1Hz each. The short comings of the driver stack are a real pain to work with across all the android deceives getting more than one to work at all reliably is hard.  Multiple at 50Hz I would be sceptical.  If you can fix on just one type of reception device then maybe.  I would get 3 or 4 TI sensor tags where you can reprogram the firmware to do the data rates you want and try testing with that.